# Sanity check: Does returning !EOF from streambuf-derived class' overflow function make sense?

Tags: c++, c++17, streambuf

I can find surprisingly little useful information about how an overridden std::streambuf::overflow function should look like to simply get each character that's written to the stream. So I asked ChatGPT for some pointers. It keeps coming back to this concept:

```
int overflow(int c)
{
    if (c == EOF)
    {
        // Flush the buffer here
        return !EOF;
    }
    // Put c in the buffer here
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        // Flush the buffer here
    }
    return c;
}
```

It's super weird that it returns `!EOF` when c is `EOF`.
[The docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow) don't elaborate what "success" means.
[This page](https://cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/overflow/) says it should return `EOF` (not `!EOF`) when called with `EOF` as the argument (or when signalling "a failure").

So: Is my suspicion correct that returning `!EOF` here is wrong and that I should return `EOF` instead?
Cookie points if you can tell me where ChatGPT got that idea from. I can't find `return !EOF;` anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is calling it with EOF as an argument considered "successful"? Also, `Traits::eof()` is a constant value, so I'm not sure what you mean by "And if the stream has reached the end of the file Treats::eof() returns true". `!EOF` becomes `false`, which becomes 0.

Comment: It's probably have to do with the function needing to return a value different from `Traits::eof()` on success. And apparently the code considers `EOF` to be a successful case.

Comment: With that said, ChatGPT is really unreliable for actual and factual information. It can generate text and code that seems good and real, but at closer inspection often isn't. There's a reason ChatGPT-generated answers have been forbidden here. I wouldn't trust any code it generates.

Comment: `!EOF` doesn't make any sense (it is just a funny way to spell the constant `false`).

Comment: There is also a `Traits::not_eof()` function. Perhaps that's what confuses the AI? Of course `not_eof()` is very different from `!EOF`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Did you delete your comment I was replying to?
Yes, ChatGPT isn't a reliable source and one needs to verify its output. That's... why I'm here. I wasn't blindly copying its output, but using it as a stepping stone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the C++ standard has to say about the return value:

> **[streambuf.virt.put]**
>
> ```
> int_type overflow(int_type c = traits::eof());
> ```
>
> **6** *Returns:* `traits::eof()` or throws an exception if the function fails.
> Otherwise, returns some value other than `traits::eof()` to indicate success.(304)
>
> (Footnote 304) Typically, `overflow` returns `c` to indicate success, except when `traits::eq_int_type(c, traits::eof())` returns `true`, in which case it returns `traits::not_eof(c)`.

Thus, the specific return value doesn't much matter, just whether it's `traits::eof()` or not. There's a (non-normative) convention you may want to follow.

Re: what "success" means:

> **[streambuf.virt.put]/5**
> *Requires:* Every overriding definition of this virtual function shall obey the following constraints:
> ...
>
> 2. Let `r` be the number of characters in the pending sequence not consumed. If `r` is nonzero then `pbase()` and `pptr()` shall be set so that: `pptr() - pbase() == r` and the `r` characters starting at `pbase()` are the associated output stream. In case `r` is zero (all characters of the pending sequence have been consumed) then either `pbase()` is set to `nullptr`, or `pbase()` and `pptr()` are both set to the same non-null value.
> 3. The function may fail if either appending some character to the associated output stream fails or if it is unable to establish `pbase()` and `pptr()` according to the above rules.

Thus, the function fails if it is unable to actually write to the underlying medium, or unable to restore the invariants. It succeeds if it managed both.

Comment: So it's just one of those boneheaded C++-isms to use an int for what should have been a bool. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @NikoO I suppose. Streams library was designed a very long time ago, by [one person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stepanov), and well predates the standardization effort. I suspect that if it were designed now, it would look very differently. My guess is, in the original design the return value was more than just a boolean; but that is lost to the mists of time.